# R: Cómo dividir un dataframe por edad y luego convertirlo a matrix

Tags: r

Tengo un `dataframe` con pacientes de muchas edades. Lo quiero dividir en dos grupos: menores o iguales a 50 y mayores a 50.

Luego necesito los resultados expresarlos en forma de matrix, porque luego necesito usar una herramienta estadística.

Lo he logrado, pero siento que al final hice trampa porque los resultados los ingresé manualmente.

Cómo podría hacer lo mismo sin este truco que empleé?

Este es mi Código:

```r
    library(vcd)
    library(dplyr)
    data("Arthritis")
    
    datos <- subset(Arthritis, Treatment=="Treated" & (Improved=="None" | Improved=="Marked"))
    
    # Eliminamos las categorías fantasmas (ya que solo seleccionamos Marked o None, y hay 0 casos para Some
    datos$Improved<-droplevels(datos$Improved)
    
    df <- datos
    
    df$group <- cut(df$Age, breaks = seq(20, 80, by=30), right = TRUE)
    df
    Marked <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% count(Improved == "Marked")
    Marked

    # Ingresamos los resultados de Marked 
    # en Grupo de Tratamiento para hacer una
    # matrix   
    Grupo_de_Tratamiento <- matrix(c(4, 17, 6, 7), nrow = 2,
                  dimnames =
                    list(c("20-50", "51-80"),
                         c("Mejoró", "NO mejoró")))

    Grupo_de_Tratamiento
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Hola! Prueba con `table(df$group, df$Improved)` justo antes de que definas `Marker`

Comment: @R18 Funciona! Gracias! Por q no la pones como respuesta para aceptarla! Otro detalle el orden de las columnas no es el correcto. Sale primero "None" y luego "Marked." Pero, debe ser al revés. Mil disculpas por tantas preguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola!

Agrego el códgio para responder a tu pregunta, incluyendo la duda que tienes en el comentario.

```
# Cargamos las librerías
  library(vcd)
  library(dplyr)
# Cargamos los datos
  data("Arthritis")

# Seleccionamos un subconjunto de datos      
  datos <- subset(Arthritis, Treatment=="Treated" & (Improved=="None" | Improved=="Marked"))
    
# Eliminamos las categorías fantasmas (ya que solo seleccionamos Marked o None, y hay 0 casos para Some
  datos$Improved<-droplevels(datos$Improved)

# Llamamos df al nuevo conjunto de datos    
  df <- datos
# Creamos la variable "group" en función de la edad 
  df$group <- cut(df$Age, breaks = seq(20, 80, by=30), right = TRUE)
# Redefinimos la variable "Improved" para obtener los valores en el orden deseado (primero "Marked" y luego "None")
  df$Improved <- factor(df$Improved, levels = c("Marked", "None"))
# Generamos la tabla que cruce "group" con "Improved"
  table(df$group, df$Improved)
```

Comment: Fantástico! Todo funciona a la perfección! Muchísimas gracias!